# where is the mistake with my fake proof?

Tags: contour-integration

I tried to [show that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453783) $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^{n+1}}=\frac {(2n)!\pi}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}$$ using contour integration

so $$\int_{C} \frac{dz}{(z^2+1)^{n+1}}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^{n+1}} +\int_{\gamma}..=2\pi i\frac{1}{n!}Res_{z=i}\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^{n+1}}$$

[image]

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^{n+1}} +0=2\pi i\frac{1}{n!}Res_{z=i}\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^{n+1}}$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^{n+1}}=\frac{2\pi i}{n!}(\frac {d^n}{dz^n}(z+i)^{-n-1})_{z=i}$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^{n+1}}=\frac{2\pi i}{n!}(-1)^np(n+1,n)(2i)^{-2n-1}$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^{n+1}}=\frac{\pi }{2^n}$$

where is $p(n,r)=(n)(n-1)......(n-r+1)$

so where is the mistake !

Comment: A very close question was asked and answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432849/contour-integration-of-int-fracdx-1x2n1?rq=1). Hope, it would be useful.

Comment: @user64494 that is exactly what I need , thanks .